# Providing support on old answers

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I've been a user for a few months now (mostly an answerer), and every once in awhile I get a notification that says a user has commented on an "old" answer (where old is > 2 months old). It's usually a follow-up question about the code, or perhaps the asker has added some things and now it isn't working like the simple example I provided.

*(For a recent example, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611115/how-to-get-jquery-tools-validation-working-in-an-overlay-dialog/4611193#4611193) out)*

I'd like to help the asker out (after all, that's what I come to the site for), but I feel like the discussion does not belong in the comments of the answer.

So my question is, **am I on the the hook for all of my answers? If so, for how long?** It seems like the best thing for an asker that's having problems with an answer that's been accepted to do is post a new question. Is this the right attitude?

Comment: I'd say you can carry on as long as you want. You are under no obligation to answer the new request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

+1 for providing an *actual example*, which I wish more meta posts did.

I would only answer / follow up on old comments on a post if I felt they were **offering improvements (or an idea for improvement)** to the post itself. Continually improving posts in tiny ways is what we're all about!

In this case, it's sort of a random "what if" followup, not anything that would fundamentally improve your original answer.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Good to hear. Super new user here, and I've been taking a mental note on some questions that I feel I'd like to incrementally add to as some of the questions are fairly old. > 6 months.